# Manage log stream while forwarding EventBridge logs to Cloudwatch on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

I am using an integration between AWS EventBridge and Okta to forward Okta logs to AWS.

The integration allows me to push the logs to EventBridge using Okta's official partner event source, but I would love to have those logs in cloudwatch.

I've created a rule for this, and now EventBridge is forwarding all my logs to CloudWatch as expected, but it is creating a new log stream for every log that reaches EventBridge, at most I've found some log streams with two logs batched.

I have not been able to find any AWS doc saying that this could be a problem in terms of billing or anything. The only problem with this is that it would be a little bit. It's less easy to manage or find logs directly in log streams... but I want to ask just to be sure.

1. Can I modify this EventBridge behavior to use only one single log stream for all Okta logs? Does this make sense? Maybe it creates one log stream per day or something like this?
2. Do you think I shouldn't worry about this? Maybe it is normal to have 1 log stream per log; I have seen many log groups with thousands of log streams. However, it looks a bit bad to me that it has one log stream for every single Okta log that reaches AWS.
3. Am I missing any billing rule that could potentially be increasing the costs of cloudwatch just because we are creating too many log streams, or does the price not depend at all on the number of log streams?

I've seen these quotas: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/cloudwatch_limits_cwl.html. That makes me think it is expected to create up to 50 log streams per second, and we have many Okta logs anyway, so I think this could be just ignored, but I would like to double-check.

I appreciate your opinion on this topic; thanks in advance for the time to read and answer my questions.

Best regards,